# Powershell GUI - Add variables to a radio button once it's selected

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, powershell

I am doing a GUI in Visual Studuio for a script I made for Powershell and I need to use radio buttons to add variables to make this script works, like for example, the script works with 5 printer brands, so the user needs to select one of this to progress. Then, for each brand you have inside the models. At the end, will execute the code to create a print queue on a selected server, which includes the variables held on the radio buttons below:

```
$maker - brand of the device.
$model - model of the device.
$modelfull - full model name for comment purposes.
$driver - print driver to assign to the print queue.
```

How can I add those variables to each radio button? I.e. I have two models, Deskjet 3050 and Deskjet 3045, how can I convert those models into a variable once user select the radio button and press Next on the window?

Below you can see example of the code from Visual Studio where is the frame with the radio buttons:

```
<Page x:Class="Print_Queue_Configuration_Tool.Maker_2"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Print_Queue_Configuration_Tool"
mc:Ignorable="d" 
d:DesignHeight="570" d:DesignWidth="754"
Title="Maker_2">
    <Grid x:Name="Maker_2_Grid">
        <Button x:Name="Maker_2_ButtonBack" Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="360,525,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="35"/>
        <Button x:Name="Maker_2_ButtonNext" Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="485,525,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="35"/>
        <Button x:Name="Maker_2_ButtonCancel" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="610,525,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="35" IsCancel="True"/>
        <Image x:Name="Maker_2_ImageLogo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44.264" Margin="480.157,30.312,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="273.843" Source="logo.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Maker_2_TextMaker_2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,140,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Please select the maker of the device:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="Maker_2_RadioMaker1" Content="Canon" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="272.25,220.25,351.75,333.75" Height="16" Width="130" GroupName="Makers_2" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="Maker_2_RadioMaker2" Content="Epson" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="272.25,260.25,351.75,293.75" Height="16" Width="130" GroupName="Makers_2" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </Grid>
</Page>
```

Here you can see how I have assigned the variables to each button, but of course it's not working:

```
$wpf.Maker_2_RadioMaker1.add_Checked({
$maker = 'Canon'
})
$wpf.Maker_2_RadioMaker2.add_Checked({
$maker = 'Epson'
})
```

Thank you!!

PS: I am new in this so I am still learning. Please be polite, remember that you were in my position once :)

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? you Variable $maker will not set? is something in the variable when you output $wpf.Maker_2_RadioMaker1?  How you start your Dialog?

Comment: You have to Adress your Buttons with findname. Your Pages must be put in a Navigationwindow.

Answer (score 0):

Here your Page is working... I had to adapt the xml a bit.

`Note the FindName to Address the Radiobuttons`

```
[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="Maker_2" Height="770" Width="800">
    <Grid x:Name="Maker_2_Grid">
        <Button x:Name="Maker_2_ButtonBack" Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="360,525,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="35"/>
        <Button x:Name="Maker_2_ButtonNext" Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="485,525,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="35"/>
        <Button x:Name="Maker_2_ButtonCancel" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="610,525,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="35" IsCancel="True"/>
        <Image x:Name="Maker_2_ImageLogo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44.264" Margin="480.157,30.312,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="273.843" Source="logo.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Maker_2_TextMaker_2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,140,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Please select the maker of the device:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="Maker_2_RadioMaker1" Content="Canon" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="272.25,220.25,351.75,333.75" Height="16" Width="130" GroupName="Makers_2" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="Maker_2_RadioMaker2" Content="Epson" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="272.25,260.25,351.75,293.75" Height="16" Width="130" GroupName="Makers_2" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </Grid>
</Window>
"@

function Check-Radios
{   
    if($this.Name -eq "Maker_2_RadioMaker1") {Write-Host "Canon"}
    if($this.Name -eq "Maker_2_RadioMaker2") {Write-Host "Epson"}
}

$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)


$window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

$window.FindName("Maker_2_RadioMaker1").add_Checked({Check-Radios})
$window.FindName("Maker_2_RadioMaker2").add_Checked({Check-Radios})



$window.ShowDialog()
```

Now it's working as requested. In Function Check-Radios you can set your variables depending on choosen Radiobutton

Comment: Hello @RoXTar, I finally managed to make the GUI works, but instead of using the radio buttons I made it to use normal buttons. I used some ideas from your example to move it forward to the initial GUI but was working partially, probably because I am not enough trained on this. Thank you very much for the effort you put on this topic

Answer (score 0):

This example meets your requirements that when you press "Next" the correct selection of the radio button is displayed. This should take you further.

```
[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="Maker_2" Height="770" Width="800">
    <Grid x:Name="Maker_2_Grid">
        <Button x:Name="Maker_2_ButtonBack" Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="360,525,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="35"/>
        <Button x:Name="Maker_2_ButtonNext" Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="485,525,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="35"/>
        <Button x:Name="Maker_2_ButtonCancel" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="610,525,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="35" IsCancel="True"/>
        <Image x:Name="Maker_2_ImageLogo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44.264" Margin="480.157,30.312,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="273.843" Source="logo.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Maker_2_TextMaker_2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,140,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Please select the maker of the device:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="Maker_2_RadioMaker1" Content="Canon" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="272.25,220.25,351.75,333.75" Height="16" Width="130" GroupName="Makers_2" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="Maker_2_RadioMaker2" Content="Epson" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="272.25,260.25,351.75,293.75" Height="16" Width="130" GroupName="Makers_2" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </Grid>
</Window>
"@

function Check-Radios
{   
   $Global:radioSelected = $this;
}

$radioSelected = $null

$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)


$window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

$window.FindName("Maker_2_RadioMaker1").add_Checked({Check-Radios})
$window.FindName("Maker_2_RadioMaker2").add_Checked({Check-Radios})
$window.FindName("Maker_2_ButtonNext").add_Click({Write-Host "You have selected: $($radioSelected.Content)"});


$window.ShowDialog()
```

**EDIT:**

here an example for an object that holds your printerdata

```
$printerList = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$printerList.Add([pscustomobject]@{Maker = "Canon";Model = "Pixma";ModelFull="Pixma0815";driver = "driverxyz1"})
$printerList.Add([pscustomobject]@{Maker = "Epson";Model = "Workforce";ModelFull="Workforce2020";driver = "driverxyz2"})
```

You can simply rewrite your "next button ClickMethod" like this...

```
$window.FindName("Maker_2_ButtonNext").add_Click({ Write-Host $($printerList | where Maker -eq $($radioSelected.Content)) });
```

it will give you the printers with selected maker

With Navigationwindow and pages you can now go to the page depending in selected printer.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, importing wpf as xaml for powershell is for me not entirely functional

I designed an example for you in which all elements were created in the code and also realized that you first select the manufacturer (radio buttons) and on the next page the model or full model, both are listed as an example. But you actually only need the combo with the full model.

here it is with Powershell

```
using namespace System.Windows
using namespace System.Windows.Controls
using namespace System.Windows.Navigation


[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("PresentationFramework")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("PresentationCore")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("WindowsBase")

function Check-Radios
{   
    $Global:selectedMaker = $this.Content
}

$printerList = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$printerList.Add([pscustomobject]@{Maker = "Canon";Model = "Pixma";ModelFull="Pixma0815";driver = "driverxyz1"})
$printerList.Add([pscustomobject]@{Maker = "Canon";Model = "Pixma";ModelFull="Pixma1615";driver = "driverxyz1"})
$printerList.Add([pscustomobject]@{Maker = "Epson";Model = "Workforce";ModelFull="Workforce2020";driver = "driverxyz2"})

$selectedMaker = "Canon";

$navigationWindow = [NavigationWindow]::new()
$navigationPage1 = [Page]::new()
$navigationPage2 = [Page]::new()
#Page with printers
$printerLabel = [Label]::new()
$printerLabel.Content = ($printerList | where Maker -eq $selectedMaker | Select -First 1).Maker
$printerModelCombo = [ComboBox]::new()
$printerModelFullCombo = [ComboBox]::new()


$printerStackPanel = [StackPanel]::new()
$printerStackPanel.AddChild($printerLabel)
$printerStackPanel.AddChild($printerModelCombo)
$printerStackPanel.AddChild($printerModelFullCombo)
$navigationPage2.Content = $printerStackPanel


#Page with radiobuttons
$radioButton1 = [RadioButton]::new()
$radioButton1.Content ="Canon"
$radioButton1.Name = "RadioCanon"
$radioButton2 = [RadioButton]::new()
$radioButton2.Content ="Epson"
$radioButton2.Name = "RadioEpson"

$radioButton1.add_Checked({Check-Radios})
$radioButton2.add_Checked({Check-Radios})
$button1 = [Button]::new()
$button1.Content = "Next"
$button1.add_Click(
{
    foreach($entry in ($printerList | where Maker -eq $selectedMaker))
    {
        # Model
        if($printerModelCombo.Items.IsEmpty -or !$printerModelCombo.Items.Content.Contains($entry.Model))
        {
            $printerModelComboItem = [ComboBoxItem]::new()
            $printerModelComboItem.Content = $entry.Model
            $printerModelCombo.AddChild($printerModelComboItem)    
        }
        # Model Full
        $printerModelFullComboItem = [ComboBoxItem]::new()
        $printerModelFullComboItem.Content = $entry.ModelFull
        $printerModelFullCombo.AddChild($printerModelFullComboItem)    
        
    }
   

    $printerModelCombo.SelectedIndex = 0
    $printerModelFullCombo.SelectedIndex = 0

    
    $navigationWindow.NavigationService.Content = $navigationPage2
})


$grid = [Grid]::new()
$gridRowDef1 = [RowDefinition]::new()
$gridRowDef2 = [RowDefinition]::new()
$gridRowDef1.Height ="4*"
$gridRowDef2.Height ="1*"


$grid.RowDefinitions.Add($gridRowDef1)
$grid.RowDefinitions.Add($gridRowDef2)


$stackPanel = [StackPanel]::new()

$stackPanel.AddChild($radioButton1)
$stackPanel.AddChild($radioButton2)
$grid.AddChild($stackPanel)
$grid.AddChild($button1)
[Grid]::SetRow($stackPanel,0)
[Grid]::SetRow($button1,1)



$navigationPage1.Content = $grid;
$navigationWindow.Title = "Navigation"
$navigationWindow.Width = 960
$navigationWindow.Height = 600
$navigationWindow.NavigationService.Content = $navigationPage1
$navigationWindow.ShowsNavigationUI = $false
$navigationWindow.ShowDialog()
```